# GPU view port render slower than CPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a dual GTX-1060 in my computer running Ubuntu 18.04
NVIDIA driver installed is:
NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0
When I set GPU render on blender 2.83 official build, the GPU render is fast
However on blender 2.90+ the GPU render is slower than the CPU render.

I tried building my own blender as well as downloading the nightly build. Both have the same issue.

Anyone know why? Or have ideas what to look at?

thanks

Comment: I'm going to suppose you have activated one of the cycles render devices under system in the preferences panel, if you have already, it's probably a hardware issue

Comment: Yes. I have. I think I found out the culprit. I had "Distributed memory across devices" checked. And for some reason that slowed down the GPU render. When I unchecked it, the GPU view port render performance improved. Interestingly enough that option is not available in 2.83. Again my system has 2 GPUs. Any idea why that option slows down performance?